# Как сравнить два пользовательских List и вывести разницу между ними

Tags: c#, linq

Есть две коллекции List, такого вида

```
    List<Answers> UserAnswers = new List<Answers>{
        new Answers(){Id = 1, Answer = 0, QuestionId = 1, AnswerVariant = null},
        new Answers(){Id = 4, Answer = 0, QuestionId = 2, AnswerVariant = null},
        new Answers(){Id = 6, Answer = 0, QuestionId = 2, AnswerVariant = null},
        new Answers(){Id = 8, Answer = 0, QuestionId = 3, AnswerVariant = null},
        new Answers(){Id = 0, Answer = 0, QuestionId = 4, AnswerVariant = "Париж"}
    };
    List<Answers> RightAnswers = new List<Answers>{
        new Answers(){Id = 3, Answer = 1, QuestionId = 1, AnswerVariant = "Рим"},
        new Answers(){Id = 4, Answer = 1, QuestionId = 2, AnswerVariant = "Москва"},
        new Answers(){Id = 6, Answer = 1, QuestionId = 2, AnswerVariant = "Рига"},
        new Answers(){Id = 7, Answer = 1, QuestionId = 3, AnswerVariant = "Нил"},
        new Answers(){Id = 10, Answer = 1, QuestionId = 4, AnswerVariant = "Париж"}
    };
```

Проверка идет `QuestionId`
 где  `AnswerVariant = null` надо сравнивать по `Id`, а где не `AnswerVariant != null` сравнивать по значению AnswerVariant

В итоге сделать лист не совпадений.

Из двух представленных выше коллекций должна получится новая коллекция такого вида

```
   List<Answers> result = new List<Answers>{
        new Answers(){Id = 1, Answer = 0, QuestionId = 1, AnswerVariant = null},

        new Answers(){Id = 8, Answer = 0, QuestionId = 3, AnswerVariant = null}

    };
```

То есть извлекаем, то что не совпало в отдельный лист. Помогите решить эту проблему.

Дополню вопрос, дело в том что длина коллекции UserAnswers иногда может быть короче RightAnswers.  В этом случаи нужно, чтобы итоговая коллекция содержала отсутствующие в UserAnswers поля.

Пример.

```
        List<Answers> UserAnswers = new List<Answers>{
            new Answers(){Id = 1, Answer = 0, QuestionId = 1, AnswerVariant = null},
            new Answers(){Id = 4, Answer = 0, QuestionId = 2, AnswerVariant = null},
            new Answers(){Id = 6, Answer = 0, QuestionId = 2, AnswerVariant = null},
        };
        List<Answers> RightAnswers = new List<Answers>{
            new Answers(){Id = 3, Answer = 1, QuestionId = 1, AnswerVariant = "Рим"},
            new Answers(){Id = 4, Answer = 1, QuestionId = 2, AnswerVariant = "Москва"},
            new Answers(){Id = 6, Answer = 1, QuestionId = 2, AnswerVariant = "Рига"},
            new Answers(){Id = 7, Answer = 1, QuestionId = 3, AnswerVariant = "Нил"},
            new Answers(){Id = 10, Answer = 1, QuestionId = 4, AnswerVariant = "Париж"}
        };

    На выходе тогда получаем

       List<Answers> result = new List<Answers>{
            new Answers(){Id = 3, Answer = 0, QuestionId = 1, AnswerVariant = null},
            new Answers(){Id = 8, Answer = 0, QuestionId = 3, AnswerVariant = null},
            new Answers(){Id = 7, Answer = 1, QuestionId = 3, AnswerVariant = "Нил"},
            new Answers(){Id = 10, Answer = 1, QuestionId = 4, AnswerVariant = "Париж"}
        };
```

Comment: почему `new Answers(){Id = 3, Answer = 1, QuestionId = 1, AnswerVariant = "Рим"},` не попало в результат?

Comment: @tym32167 Да извиняюсь. Сейчас поправлю

Comment: @tym32167 в случаи результирующего списка можно, чтобы было AnswerVariant = null

Answer (score 1):

Ну самый простой вариант как по мне - это что то вроде этого:

```
public List<Answers> GetAnswers(List<Answers> one, List<Answers> two)
{
    var list = new List<Answers>();

    foreach (var userAnswer in one)
    {
        var answer = userAnswer.AnswerVariant != null 
            ? two.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AnswerVariant == userAnswer.AnswerVariant)
            : two.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == userAnswer.Id);

        if (answer == null)
            list.Add(userAnswer);
    }

    return list;
}
```

То есть мы создаем метод, который делает следующее:

- Принимает на вход две коллекции для сравнивания.
- Инициализирует пустую коллекцию для возвращения.
- Проходится по первой коллекции (как я понял ответы пользователя).
- Ищет во второй коллекции объект, который подходит под наши требования (если `AnswerVariant == null`, то ищем схожий объект по `AnswerVariant`, если же нет, то по `Id`. Если нечего не находится, то метод `FirstOrDefault` вернет нам Null.).
- Проверяем полученный объект на Null, если он не найден, то как я уже говорил `FirstOrDefault` вернет Null, а значит он уникальный и мы можем смело добавлять его в нашу локальную коллекцию.
- Все, возвращаем в конце цикла нашу полученную коллекцию.

Вызов:

```
var list = GetAnswerses(UserAnswers, RightAnswers);
```

Результат:

[image: Result]

Comment: Забыл добавить, что длина UserAnswer может быть иногда меньше RightAnswers как мне в таком случаи добавить в итоговую коллекцию не достающие позиции?

Comment: @shatoidil Вы можете либо добавить все нужные элементы перед `return list;` (примерно так: `list.AddRange(two.Where(x => one.All(a => a.Id != x.Id)));`), либо попробовать переписать проход, но уже по коллекции RightAnswers.

Answer (score 1):

Не самый эффективный, но короткий способ

```
var result = UserAnswers
                .Where(x=> 
                    string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.AnswerVariant) 
                    ? 
                        RightAnswers.All(r=>r.Id != x.Id) 
                    : 
                        RightAnswers.All(r=>r.AnswerVariant != x.AnswerVariant))
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Забыл добавить, что длина UserAnswer может быть иногда меньше RightAnswers как мне в таком случаи добавить в итоговую коллекцию не достающие позиции?

Comment: @shatoidil приведите пример списков на входе и на выходе и добавьте этот пример в вопрос.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос